# Elasticsearch fuzzy search phrase with dash

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search, search-suggestion

I am trying to find a way to index a document with a description like "In-N-Out Burger" and do a search like "in n out" or "in and out" or just straight "in-n-out" and have it return the "In-N-Out Burger" document. Looking through documents I am confused on how to handle a dash while indexing or searching. Any suggestions?

My current setting and mapping:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/objects -d '{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "lower": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": [ "lowercase" ] 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/objects/object/_mapping -d '{
    "object" : {
        "properties" : {
            "objectDescription" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "fields" : {
                    "lower": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "lower"
                    }
                }
            },
            "suggest" : {
                "type" : "completion",
                "analyzer" : "simple",
                "search_analyzer" : "simple",
                "payloads" : true
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: Any luck with my answer?

Comment: I am so sorry! I am out of the country right now and can't play with it. As soon as I get home I will let you know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen any issues when I made index with your settings and put document:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/objects/object/001 -d '{
  "description": "In-N-Out Burger",
  "name" : "first_document"
}'
```

And then tried to find it:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/objects/object/_search?q=in+and+out&pretty'
{
  "took" : 6,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.05038611,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "objects",
      "_type" : "object",
      "_id" : "001",
      "_score" : 0.05038611,
      "_source" : {
        "description" : "In-N-Out Burger",
        "name" : "first_document"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

or

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/objects/object/_search?pretty&q=in-n-out'
{
  "took" : 8,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.23252454,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "objects",
      "_type" : "object",
      "_id" : "001",
      "_score" : 0.23252454,
      "_source" : {
        "description" : "In-N-Out Burger",
        "name" : "first_document"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

As you can see it can be found. Analyzer uses '-' as delimiter and divides phrase on tokens when you index document and when you try to find it. You can see this work:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/objects/_analyze?pretty=true' -d 'In-N-Out Burger'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "in",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 2,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 0
  }, {
    "token" : "n",
    "start_offset" : 3,
    "end_offset" : 4,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "out",
    "start_offset" : 5,
    "end_offset" : 8,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 2
  }, {
    "token" : "burger",
    "start_offset" : 9,
    "end_offset" : 15,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 3
  } ]
}
```